# Display the name of the current open file?

Tags: c#

I have a code that opens a file and displays its contents to 96 different text boxes. One line is equivalent to one text box. My question is whenever I open a file, I want its file name to be displayed in a label how will I be able to do that. here is my code

```
try

   {

    using (OpenFileDialog OpenFD = new OpenFileDialog()
    {Filter =  "Text Documents| *.txt", Multiselect = false,})
    {
        if(OpenFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
          using(StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(OpenFD.FileName))
          {

            MinArd1.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd1.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd2.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd2.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd3.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd3.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd4.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd4.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd5.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd5.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd6.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd6.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd7.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd7.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd8.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd8.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd9.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd9.Text =  Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd10.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd10.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd11.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd11.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd12.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd12.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd13.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd13.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd14.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd14.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd15.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd15.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd16.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd16.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd17.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd17.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd18.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd18.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd19.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd19.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd20.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd20.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd21.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd21.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd22.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd22.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd23.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd23.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd24.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd24.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd25.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd25.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd26.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd26.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd27.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd27.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd28.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd28.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd29.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd29.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd30.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd30.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd31.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd31.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd32.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd32.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd33.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd33.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd34.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd34.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd35.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd35.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd36.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd36.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd37.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd37.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd38.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd38.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd39.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd39.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd40.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd40.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd41.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd41.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd42.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd42.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd43.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd43.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd44.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd44.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd45.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd45.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd46.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd46.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd47.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd47.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
            MinArd48.Text = Sr.ReadLine();
            MaxArd48.Text = Sr.ReadLine(); 
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("mali");
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  You have the filename: `OpenFD.FileName`  Is the problem the label?

Comment: @RetiredNinja `OpenFD.FileName` Returns the complete filepath of the file being read. I think TS wants is only the Filename not the complete path.

Comment: @Hexxed That may be completely true, but it requires assuming information not given by the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This is in case if you want to get the filename only since `OpenFD.FileName` returns the complete filepath of the file

```
myLabel.Text = Path.GetFileName(OpenFD.FileName);
```